# Webpack running in watch mode on its own

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a webpack config —

```
{
    entry: ['./src/index.js'],
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'public'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: '#inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: './public'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'},
        {
          test: /.js$/,
          loader: 'babel',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          query: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
            presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
            plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-object-rest-spread']
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I run the webpack command from the command line it never comes to a stop.

[image]
**UPDATE:**
Apparently it is running in Watch mode. Though I have not passed the watch flag.

**UPDATE 1:**
The problem was with a npm module `config` — https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Reserved-Words.
The module contains some reserved words which include `watch` and was auto added to my configuration.

Comment: According to this image, it was done. Did you enable the `watch` mode?

Comment: Its done but the process doesn't end. Watch mode isn't enabled. You can see the config and the command I have used.

Comment: Can you post all the input and output from your commandline?

Comment: Every thing is there in the snapshot. In the first line I call `webpack` and then `bundle.js` is created, but the process doesn't end.

Comment: Try to remove your devServer settings.

Comment: Apparently its running in watch mode. But I did not pass the watch params.